# xUnit test using Moq for Task<IActionResult> type method

Tags: c#, moq

I am new to Moq framework. Here i am trying to write a simple xUnit test for following method in mvc project. on last part of example code i added my xUnit test method where i am not getting idea how to setup the `commandMock.Setup`. Any idea what should i setup on it?

xUnit test to be written on this method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(UpdateTermsAndConditionCommand command)
        {
            var response = await Mediator.Send(command);
            return response.Success ? this.SuccessSaveResult(response.Message) : this.FailSaveResult(CommonResources.msgErrorSomthingWentWrong);
        }
```

UpdateTermsAndConditionCommand class:

```
public class UpdateTermsAndConditionCommand : IRequest<ResponseDetail>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "labelEnglishTermsAndCondition", ResourceType = typeof(TermsAndConditionResources))]
        [XSSIgnore]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "msgEnglishTermsConditionRequire", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(TermsAndConditionResources))]
        public string EngTermsAndCondition { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "labelDutchTermsAndCondition", ResourceType = typeof(TermsAndConditionResources))]
        [XSSIgnore]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "msgDutchTermsConditionRequire", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(TermsAndConditionResources))]
        public string DutchTermsAndCondition { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "labelGermanTermsAndCondition", ResourceType = typeof(TermsAndConditionResources))]
        [XSSIgnore]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "msgGermanTermsConditionRequire", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(TermsAndConditionResources))]
        public string GermanTermsAndCondition { get; set; }
    }
```

Mediator class:

```
[XSSFilter]
    public abstract class BaseController<T> : Controller
    {
        private ISender _mediator;
        
        private ILogger<T> _logger;
        protected ISender Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ISender>();
        protected ILogger<T> Logger => _logger ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<T>>();
        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Pdf_Export_Save(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
        {
            var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

            return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
        }
        
        public async Task<List<LanguageListItemDto>> GetLanguages()
        {
            var response = await Mediator.Send(new GetLanguageListQuery());
            return response.Languages;
        }
    }
```

xUnit Test using Moq:

```
  [Fact]
        public void SaveXUnit()
        {

            //arrange
            var commandMock = new Mock<UpdateTermsAndConditionCommand>();
            var controller = new TermsandConditionController();
            commandMock.Setup(x => x.Execute());//here i am not getting idea how to setup the command

            //act

            //assert

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UpdateTermsAndConditionCommand` is a `class` which you can instantiate (`var command = new UpdateTermsAndConditionCommand { }`) and *cannot* be mocked.

Only `abstract classes` and `interfaces` can be mocked.

The easiest way is to *inject* dependencies in the `class` you want to test and mock these. You can start by reading up on [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)